# In statistics how does one find the mean of a function w.r.t the uniform probability measure?

Tags: probability, mean, expected-value, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

I am unfamiliar in statistics. My knowledge is in pure mathematics.

Suppose $n\in\mathbb{N}$, where $X$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra of Caratheodory-measurable sets such that $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $f$ is a measurable function where $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$.

*Edit:* For some measure $\mu$ on measurable space $(X,\Sigma)$, the average w.r.t to $\mu$, where $0<\mu(X)<\infty$, is:

$$\text{avg}_f(X)=\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int_{X}f(x) \; d\mu$$

However, in mathematics $\mu(X)$ need not equal $1$ but I wish to know, *in detail*, how to get the same result using a probability measure.

*Question:* How does one use statistics to find the mean of $f$, using the uniform probability measure on $X$ (explained [here](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2020/11/the_uniform_measure.html#:%7E:text=The%20uniform%20measure%20is%20the,it%20into%20a%20general%20definition.) and [here in pg.32-37](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.11184.pdf))?

I assume that in statistics the expected value is the same as the mean, but in textbooks, we're shown the expected value applies to the probability density function or the cumulative distribution function.

Furthermore, when the Lebesgue measure is defined $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue-measurable sets, which satisfy the Caratheodory criterion, I heard it's not a good idea to use the mean of $f$ w.r.t the uniform probability measure when:

1. $X$ is countably infinite ([the uniform probability measure does not exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255667/125918))
2. $X$ has infinite or zero Lebesgue Measure
3. $f$ is an infinite number of points that covers an infinite expanse of space in general.

*(Optional):* How do we find the mean of $f$ for these cases?

Comment: @Ben Sorry, stupid mistake.

Comment: You apply the definition of expectation or, nearly equivalently, [LOTUS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=LOTUS).

Comment: why, it's simply $\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int f d\mu$, or am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnMadden I assumed you were talking to Whuber. I always thought in statistics there's a different approach to averaging over functions but since I have a purely mathematical background, I have no idea. Is the use of uniform distribution necessary?

Comment: When you assume a uniform distribution, you have to use a uniform distribution!  If you use some other measure, you would integrate against it.

Comment: @whuber I added a more, in detail explanation. I looked at the definition of expectation but I am not sure how to apply it to a mathematical function. I only see it used for probability density function or cumulative distribution function.

Comment: RE the final three cases: Usually there is no intrinsic definition. It's tempting, for instance, to use a hypervolume to normalize a measure-zero set (such as arclength to define a uniform measure on a circle in the plane). But not all measure-zero sets have such hypervolumes and even when they do, there can be multiple conflicting ways to define a "natural" uniform measure on them. This all goes to show that probability measures are not canonically equivalent to measurable subsets.  For more, read about [Bertrand's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: I'm going to use the notation $\mathscr{X}$ for the set that you call $X$ and I'm going to define a random vector $\mathbf{X}$ as a uniform random vector on that set.  It is better to avoid standard upper-case symbols for sets in this context and use script fonts instead.  This avoids notational conflation between random variables and the support sets over which they're defined.*

The expected value is fairly simple in this case.  Suppose we let $\mathbf{X} \sim \text{Uniform}(\mathscr{X})$ denote a uniform random variable on the set $\mathscr{X} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $p_{\mathbf{X}}$ denote its density function.  (If you are looking for a rigorous transition from the probability measure, the density function is a [Radon-Nikodym derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) of the probability measure; the latter in this case is the Lebesgue measure over the set $\mathscr{X}$.)  Then using the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) we have:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(f(\mathbf{X})) 
&= \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(\mathbf{x}) \cdot p_{\mathbf{X}}(\mathbf{x}) \ d \mathbf{x} \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(\mathbf{x}) \cdot \frac{\mathbb{I}(\mathbf{x} \in \mathscr{X})}{|\mathscr{X}|} \ d \mathbf{x} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{|\mathscr{X}|}  \int \limits_{\mathscr{X}} f(\mathbf{x}) \ d \mathbf{x}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

In practice, computation of this expected value may be complicated if the set $\mathscr{X}$ is complicated.  If analytic integration does not give a closed form solution then a general and relatively simple way to compute the expected value (up to high accuracy) is with [importance sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling).  To do this, we produce values $\mathbf{X}_1,\mathbf{X}_2,...,\mathbf{X}_M \sim \text{IID }g$ for some density function $g$ with support $\mathscr{X} \subseteq \text{support} (g) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ (hopefully with support fairly close to $\mathscr{X}$) and we use the estimator:

$$\begin{align}
\hat{\mu}_{M}
&\equiv \frac{\sum_{i=1}^M \mathbb{I}(\mathbf{X}_i \in \mathscr{X}) \cdot f(\mathbf{X}_i)/g(\mathbf{X}_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^M \mathbb{I}(\mathbf{X}_i \in \mathscr{X})/ g(\mathbf{X}_i)}.
\end{align}$$

From the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) we can establish that $\mathbb{E}(f(\mathbf{X})) = \lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} \hat{\mu}_{M}$ so if we take $M$ to be large then we should get a reasonably good computation of the expected value of interest.

Comment: Are there cases where importance sampling cannot be defined? Consider for instance fractal $\mathscr{X}$, countably infinite $\mathscr{X}$, or an infinite amount of pseudo-random, non-uniformly distributed points in space $[a,b]\times[c,d]$, where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ where $a\to-\infty$ and $b\to\infty$, and $c\to-\infty$ and $d\to\infty$.

Comment: Importance sampling essentially requires three things: (1) you need to be able to compute whether or not a point $\mathbf{x}$ is in the set $\mathscr{X}$ or not; (2) you need to be able to generate points from a density $g$ that is on a support that covers $\mathscr{X}$ but is not too much bigger than it; and (3) you have to be able to compute $f(\mathbf{x})$ and $g(\mathbf{x})$ for each point $\mathbf{x} \in \mathscr{X}$.  So long as you have those things, you can implement importance sampling.

Comment: +1.  It would be good to mention the problematic nature of the question when the "arbitrary set" is either not measurable or has measure zero.  E.g., what if $X$ is the unit circle in the plane?

Comment: @whuber I corrected my post one last time. Let me know if there’s still something wrong.

Comment: The correction is appreciated, but it has introduced the mysterious and undefined symbol "$A.$"  I think that all that's going on here is whenever you have a finite non-negative measure $\mu$ on a space $X$ (that is, $\mu(X)\lt \infty$), you can create an associated probability measure $\Pr$ by defining $\Pr(A)=\mu(A)/\mu(X)$ for all measurable sets $A\subset X.$  $1/\mu(X)$ is known as a "normalization constant" and in many practical problems it doesn't need to be computed.  These are problems where all you need are probability ratios, so that $\Pr(A):\Pr(B)=\mu(A)/\mu(B).$

Comment: @whuber I made another stupid mistake. It was supposed to be $X$ not $A$.

Comment: @Ben I know it’s a little late but does $\mathbb{I}(x\in A)$ stand for  the $1_{A}(x)$?  This appears to be the same as the “probability $x$ is in $A$” or $P(x\in A)$.

Comment: @Arbuja: Yes, the first one.  I intend for this to denote the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

Comment: @Ben Suppose the probability density function does not exist but the cumulative distribution function does. If $C_{\mathbf{x}}$ is the cumulative distribution function, do we replace $p_{X}$ with the derivative of $C_{\mathbf{x}}$ or (in mathematical notation) $dC_{\mathbf{x}}$.

Comment: @Arbuja: If the CDF is differentiable then $p_\mathbf{X}$ would be its density, so there is no difference.  (Also, that is *not* the standard mathematical notation for a derivative.)

Comment: @Ben Let me clarify, suppose $\mathscr{X}$ is the Cantor set and $f:\mathscr{X}\to\mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)=x$. What would $p_{\mathbf{X}}$ be? From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2011489/125918) it seems the probability density function does not exist. Should we use the cumulative distribution function or $d\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{x}}$ instead?